# React-Native Server Error When making a simple API request

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios, http-get

I have a frontend in react-native that makes an API call using the `axios` library; its shown below:

```
function addItem(item) {
if (!item) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter a valid item.', [{text: 'Ok'}]);
} else {
    axios.get('/additem', {
        Id: items[items.length - 1].id + 1,
        Text: item
    })
    .then((res) => {
        setItems([...items, {id: res.id, text: res.text}])
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am making a GET request to an endpoint, and using the response data.

Here is what my backend endpoint looks like in Node.js (using Express.js):

```
app.get('/additem', (req, res) => {
const item = new Item({
    id: req.body.Id,
    text: req.body.Text
});

item.save()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

The `save()` function and `Item` object are just specific to MongoDB, so don't worry too much about that.
I am using a `proxy` to "connect" the backend and frontend, meaning, I have added this to my `package.json` file in my frontend:

```
{
"name": "firstProj",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"proxy": "https://localhost:5000",
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
```

localhost:5000 is where my node.js backend is running

Now when I try to access the endpoint via my frontend, react-native yells at me saying this:

```
  LOG      [Error: Network Error]
```

Zero clue why this is happening. Any help is appreciated. :) Let me know if you need more information from my end.

Thanks a ton.

EDIT:
this is the full error when not caught by my code:

```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error
createError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99656:26
handleError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99560:27
dispatchEvent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32348:31
setReadyState@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31432:33
__didCompleteResponse@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31248:29
emit@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:3537:42
__callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2765:36
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2497:31
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2496:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: Can you provide the error log in the express server

Comment: Or you can try changing the request to 

 `axios.get('/additem', {
        params:{
             Id: items[items.length - 1].id + 1,
             Text: item
          }
    })
`

Comment: @Musthafa I added the full error list to the post, I've tried adding the "params" still no luck :(

Comment: Okay,maybe it's due to we need to send the params in a string format. Change the params to `params:JSON.stringify({Id:[items.length - 1].id+1, Text:item})`

Comment: just a question, but are you defining the root URL for axios? `axios.get('/addItem')` is querying your UI app not your API. What happens if you use the full url to your backend? try `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/addItem')`

Comment: Yes. I think @alilland answer will fix the problem

Comment: @Musthafa changing the syntax of the params did not fix the issue :(

Comment: @alilland I have tried that with the full url, with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, and they all provide me with the same error sadly :(

Comment: I appreciate your guys help though!

Comment: Can you try setting request and response headers in the react native request and express backend?

Comment: here are two frontend gists with a samples of what my company does for all things using `axios`,https://gist.github.com/alilland/f8c84966c79d77ad4a5be7ec93fb9dc2  we wrap our API interactions with our API's default `headers` and `baseURL`. This sits as a library that we pull into every component where API queries are needed. Here is a second gist showing how it's used: https://gist.github.com/alilland/e69c2932f4303208f4798090529e9ad7

Comment: @alilland thank you for these resources. Its much appreciated. I'll check it out and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

just Remember to not put http://localhost:PORT into API Address because it will not work in that way

the way you should do it is first find your internet IP address on your machine like :

108.67.122.124

and then you change setting in your backend Service and replace localhost with this :

108.67.122.124:PORT

and then Address it like that to your AXIOS or whatever library you use

So lets wrap it again :

DONT address your react native like http:localhost:5000 instead do it like 108.67.122.124:5000 In that way it will fully work